# Traduction de « performer »

Tags: traduction, anglais, professions, spectacle

Le mot anglais *performer* se traduit généralement comme interprète. Cependant, il est possible, en anglais, d'utiliser ce même mot dans un contexte péjoratif :

> He's no artist, he's just a performer.

En français, le terme *interprète* s'utilise mal pour exprimer ainsi que l'on considère que quelqu'un n'est pas un artiste lorsqu'« il ne fait que répéter », et qu'il ne crée rien. Quel serait le mot français qui exprimerait bien cette idée.

Note : Gardez en tête que cette question n'a pas pour but de lancer un débat à savoir si un interprète est un artiste ou non.

Comment: Pour le sens péjoratif, je dirais _amateur_: _Ce n'est qu'un amateur_. Mais il doit y avoir mieux.

Comment: U'utiliserais *amateur* pour indiquer soit péjorativement que quelqu'un n'a pas de talent, ou pour indiquer positivement que c'est quelqu'un qui aime ça. Sans qu'il sache créer, un non-artiste-interprète peut être très talentueux! ;-)

Comment: Pour un pianiste, un _gueux_ (si il joue du piano à gueux)

Comment: "Performer" est utilisé dans un contexte péjoratif quand on veut insister sur l'aspect de réutilisation d'un contenu non original, en impliquant que les artistes créent un contenu nouveau à chaque fois (ce qui se discute). Le mot d'interprète peut être utilisé exactement dans le même sens, je ne vois aucun obstacle à traduire par "interprète", qui peut très bien prendre un aspect de mépris sournois. Ce sens se comprend très bien en français aussi, il me semble.

Comment: @Atorgael :
Exact, dans mon esprit acteur fait référence au cinéma : "*M-ou-Mme X. exploite le même personnage à la ville comme à l'écran, mais est incapable de monter sur scène ... ce n'est pas un comédien, mais un acteur*" Dans ce cas l'acteur peut être entendu comme 'performer' et l'interprète comme comédien. Bien entendu, il s'agit d'apprécier le talent d'une personne, sans augurer de celui des représentants de chaque profession qui peuvent exceller dans l'un ou l'autre domaine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'ai souvent entendu la distinction **artiste / poseur** :

- **l'artiste** crée des oeuvres pour exprimer une sensibilité esthétique, il agit en produisant des oeuvres qui ont une valeur indépendante de tout auditoire ou public
- **le poseur** (qui peut cependant avoir des qualités d'interprétation, en effet) essaie de plaire à un public, et pour arriver à cette fin il utilise le travail d'autres artistes (ce qui n'est bien sûr pas infâmant, nombre d'artistes ont interprété le travail de leurs pairs) sans rien produire lui-même d'original.

Cet usage n'est pas universellement répandu, ce n'est qu'une possibilité qui m'est apparue, peut-être correspond-elle à ton besoin ?

Comment: 15 mois après que j'aie posé la question, je crois que « poseur » est le terme adéquatement péjoratif que je cherchais. Merci!

Answer (score 10):

Je dirais qu'il n'y a pas de différence entre l'anglais et le français ici. « performer » peut être utilisé avec ou sans connotation péjorative, pour « interprète » c'est la même chose. Qu'il y ait débat sur le lien entre interprète et artiste ne change rien.

Edit: pour préciser ma conception du mot *interprète* en français: c'est aussi ce mot qui est utilisé en informatique pour nommer un programme qui exécute une suite d'instructions, et son but premier est bien de faire ce qu'on lui dit de faire. (Certains interprètes peuvent avoir un comportement un peu plus particulier sur les mêmes suites d'instructions, un peu comme dans le cas de l'art, mais là on rejoint le débat…)

Comment: Lire (et relire) cette réponse m'a fait repensé à la problématique. Je partais de l'idée que je voulais exclure la notion de talent du mot * interprète*, mais en fait, c'est plutôt qu'il ne faut pas associer *interprète* et *artiste*. Pour faire le parallèle avec l'informatique, la classe Interprète n'implémente pas IArtiste! ;-)

Comment: En informatique on utilise généralement le mot interpréteur

Comment: @Alex: voir la section [Terme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpr%C3%A8te_%28informatique%29#Terme) sur la page wikipedia ;-)

Comment: @Stéphane Section non sourcée de Wikipedia. Mais, j'admets que le concept s'apparente à un interprète qui lit un script. (au théâtre par ex.) Même si "interpréteur" semble plus courant.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu parler d'interprète en informatique, mais d'interpréteur.

Comment: Exactement, le problème de la question est le coup classique de ne prendre le sens du mot anglais que dans une expression donnée, et non de manière globale.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que *saltimbanque* pourrait correspondre au sens recherché.

Comment: *Saltimbanque* est effectivement une excellente traduction pour *performer*, au sens ou ce terme n'inclue pas uniquement des musiciens. La notion de l’absence de talent est cependant « lacquante ».

Comment: @Tipx « La notion de l'absence de talent **manque** cependant » ou « **il manque** cependant la notion de l'absence de talent ».

Answer (score 4):

Je propose *exécutant*, bien que ce terme ne soit pas réservé au monde du spectacle. Il n'exclut pas une certaine forme de virtuosité technique mais réalisée sans âme ou sans conviction.

Answer (score 1):

Le terme "Acteur" peut aussi correspondre à la situation décrite. Dans ce cas, le terme acteur réduit l'artiste à son métier en lui déniant sa qualité artistique.

*"Ce n'est pas un artiste, il n'est qu'un acteur."*

Answer (score 1):

Il y a aussi une connotation spectaculaire lorsque l'on pense à la personne qui exécute une performance (sur scène dans le contexte sous entendu, mais aussi au cirque, sur un stade ..) sans qu'il y ait quoique ce soit en rapport avec la notion d'artiste.

Il s'agit d'effectuer une prestation qui demande des qualités particulières, voire exceptionnelles, surtout dans le monde du spectacle.

Interprète implique, au moins dans l'exécution artistique, l'apport d'une partie émotionnelle ou sensible de soi pour valoriser une œuvre, alors qu'une performance manifesterait plutôt la partie égotique de l'intervenant.

Pour compliquer le tout, un artiste peut être un bon 'performer' ou non, et vice-versa.

On peut dire qu'une personne travaillant dans les spectacles (les arts vivants) a effectué une bonne *prestation* ou non, malheureusement on ne peut traduire 'performer' par prestataire.

Il faut donc compléter la traduction par une mise en situation, si l'on veut éviter le franglais

C'est un bon 'performer' est parfois entendu pour signifier les compétences spectaculaires (ou la maîtrise de la scène) de quelqu'un.

Answer (score 0):

Je trouve que le terme *exécutant* est le mieux adapté pour le sens de cette phrase. Cela signifie que l'interprète ne fait que répéter ce qu'il appris sans véritablement réfléchir ou apporter sa touche personnelle.